# why encapsulate functions within $()

Tags: jquery

I'm taking Udacity's "javascript design patterns" and I stumbled upon a code that calls jQuery's object like described below:

In retain.js file (https://github.com/draconar/ud989-retain/blob/master/js/retain.js), the code starts with a call to the jQuery object "$()". Inside it, we can find the Model-Octopus-View declared and initialized.

```
$(function(){

    var model = {
        init: function() {
            if (!localStorage.notes) {
                localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify([]);
            }
        },
        add: function(obj) {
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
            data.push(obj);
            localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        getAllNotes: function() {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
        }
    };


    var octopus = {
        addNewNote: function(noteStr) {
            model.add({
                content: noteStr
            });
            view.render();
        },

        getNotes: function() {
            return model.getAllNotes();
        },

        init: function() {
            model.init();
            view.init();
        }
    };


    var view = {
        init: function() {
            this.noteList = $('#notes');
            var newNoteForm = $('#new-note-form');
            var newNoteContent = $('#new-note-content');
            newNoteForm.submit(function(e){
                octopus.addNewNote(newNoteContent.val());
                newNoteContent.val('');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            view.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var htmlStr = '';
            octopus.getNotes().forEach(function(note){
                htmlStr += '<li class="note">'+
                        note.content +
                    '</li>';
            });
            this.noteList.html( htmlStr );
        }
    };

    octopus.init();
});
```

I don't get why it resides inside the jQuery object and I also don't get how do we get access to it during the life of the application. E.g., I tried to manipulate it through the console, to no avail.

Comment: Show the relevant code excerpt **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: I would not call `$()` the "jQuery object". It's not an object, it's a function. [Here are the docs for it](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/). You'll be interested in the last form of it (the jQuery function has different behavior depending on what arguments you pass to it). If you were to use the jQuery function to select some elements on the page, it then *returns* a jQuery object.

Comment: `$(fn)` will call `fn` (a function reference) on document ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does two things:

1. `$(function() { ... })` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.  This makes sure that all of your HTML markup is done loading and has been parsed by the browser - at which point it is safe to modify the DOM.
2. It provides a closure for your code which prevents global scope pollution and makes it harder for external scripts to modify or hijack your code.  Closure is good.  If you want to access something from the console, you will need to first "expose" it to the world by setting a variable on the global (window) object.  So if you have a variable `foo` you want to access via the console, somewhere you will need to write `window.foo = foo;`... and be sure to remove that code before you publish your app.

Answer (score 1):

The code does the following:

```
$(function(){

    // Some procedural stuff here... declaring variables and functions, 
    // assigning values to variables, etc.

});
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
function thingsToDo(){
    // Procedural stuff
}
$(thingsToDo);
```

Which is a shorthand for:

```
function thingsToDo(){
    // Procedural stuff
}
$(document).ready(thingsToDo);
```

Which is jQuery talk for

```
Please execute all that procedural stuff when the DOM is ready. If the DOM
is already ready right now, you can execute the stuff now. Thank you.
```